# Redirect magento index.php to http://mysite.com/

Tags: .htaccess, magento, magento-1.7

I have done in

Configuration > Web > Use Web Server Rewrites and change to 'Yes'.

When i have set in htaccess Redirect 301 /index.php http://mysite.com/ .Gives error "problem to loading page".

I just want to mysite.com/index.php redirect to root url mysite.com/ in magento.

Is this posible?

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try mod_rewrite rule:

```
# remove index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=302,NC,NE]
```

Also make sure this is first rule.